# C# Winforms Validating DataGridView Cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` on a WinForms that the user pastes the data or imports from an Excel file. I'm validating the cells through a button click, which calls the method below. I'm wondering if there is a ***"better"*** way of writing the `if/else` statements.

**Note**: I am aware of the `DataGridView.CellValidating` event but I would rather not use that, unless someone suggests a better work around using this event than the method I have written.

Here is my method being called from the `button_Click`

```
private async void ValidateGridCells()
    {
        string numberHeader = dgvAddNumbers.Columns[0].HeaderText;
        string accountHeader = dgvAddNumbers.Columns[1].HeaderText;
        string statusHeader = dgvAddNumbers.Columns[2].HeaderText;
        string dateHeader = dgvAddNumbers.Columns[3].HeaderText;
        string acLengthHeader = dgvAddNumbers.Columns[4].HeaderText;

        if (dgvAddNumbers.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAddNumbers.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    cell.ErrorText = "";
                }
            }
        }

        if (numberHeader.Equals("Number"))
        {
            //Number cannot exist in DB already from Numbers table
            //Number can only appear once in datagridview
            //Number must be 10 digits ONLY
            var numbersList = new List<string>();
            var aniListFromDb = new List<dynamic>(await DataAccess.FetchNumbersFromDatabase(ConfigReader.GetValue("ConnectionStrings", "DB"), ConfigReader.GetValue("StoredProcedures", "FetchAllNumbers")));
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAddNumbers.Rows)
            {
                numbersList.Add(row.Cells[0].ToString());
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAddNumbers.Rows)
            {
                if (row.IsNewRow) { continue; }
                //Check for empty Number and length
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()) || row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Length != 10)
                {
                    row.Cells[0].ErrorText = "Number must be 10 digits";
                    continue;
                }
                //Check for multiples of the same Number
                else if (numbersList.Where(a => a == row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()).Count() > 0)
                {
                    row.Cells[0].ErrorText = "Number already exists in the grid";
                    continue;
                }
                //Check if Number is already in DB
                else if (aniListFromDb.Where(a => a.ANI == row.Cells[0]).Count() > 0)
                {
                    row.Cells[0].ErrorText = "Number already exists in the database";
                    continue;
                }
                //Check for valid NPA/NXX
                else
                {
                    var npa = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()[..3];
                    var nxx = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(3, 3);

                    //Validate NPA
                    if (_npaList.Where(x => x.NPA == npa).Count() == 0)
                    {
                        row.Cells[0].ErrorText = "NPA not valid";
                    }
                    //Validate NXX
                    if (_nxxList.Where(x => x.NXX == nxx).Count() == 0)
                    {
                        row.Cells[0].ErrorText = "NXX not valid";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (accountHeader.Equals("Account Number"))
        {
            //Account Number must exist
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAddNumbers.Rows)
            {
                if (row.IsNewRow) { continue; }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    row.Cells[1].ErrorText = "Account Number is missing";
                    continue;
                }
                else if (MainForm.activeAccounts.Where(a => a.AccountNumber == row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()).Count() == 0)
                {
                    row.Cells[1].ErrorText = "Account Number is not valid";
                }
            }
        }
        if (statusHeader.Equals("Status"))
        {
            //Status needs to be the same as in enums
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAddNumbers.Rows)
            {
                if (row.IsNewRow) { continue; }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    row.Cells[2].ErrorText = "Status is missing";
                    continue;
                }
                else if (!Enum.GetNames(typeof(FormConstants.StatusDropDownValues)).Any(e => row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains(e)))
                {
                    row.Cells[2].ErrorText = "Status is not valid";
                }
            }
        }
        if (dateHeader.Equals("Active Date"))
        {
            //Activate Date must be current or greater date
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAddNumbers.Rows)
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                if (row.IsNewRow) { continue; }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    dt = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    row.Cells[3].ErrorText = "Activation Date is missing";
                    continue;
                }
                else if (dt < today)
                {
                    row.Cells[3].ErrorText = "Date must be today or in the future";
                }
            }

        }
        if (acLengthHeader.Equals("AC Length"))
        {
            //Account code length needs to be >=0 and <=10
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAddNumbers.Rows)
            {
                if (row.IsNewRow) { continue; }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    row.Cells[4].ErrorText = "Account length is missing";
                    continue;
                }
                else if ((int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString()) < 0) || (int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString()) > 10))
                {
                    row.Cells[4].ErrorText = "Length can only be between 0-10";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I am pasting the data to the `DataGridView` from the `KeUp` event on the grid:

```
private void PasteToDataGridView(bool clearRows)
    {
        var gridView = this.dgvAddNumbers;
        DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            if (clearRows)
            {
                if (gridView.RowCount > 0)
                    gridView.Rows.Clear();
            }                

            string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
            foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
            {
                string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

                int myRowIndex = gridView.Rows.Add();

                using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = gridView.Rows[myRowIndex])
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                        myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a DataSource for your DataGridView? The best way of validation is validating the Data in the DataSource, it could be a `DataTable`, or it could be a `List<MyDataModel>`, etc.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I don't have a DataSource per se, but I updated my question to include how I am pasting the data to the DataGridView